# Modal not hiding after submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I've been trying to make a function work to post comments using a modal.
The JavaScript take care of posting the comment, but the 'hide' option is not working.
I've been looking around for hours over this issue and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.
Any help will be welcomed. Thank you !

```js
function postcomment(id) {
  $("#postcommentid").val(id);
  $('#postComments').modal('show');
  return false;
}

$('#frmpostcomments').submit(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  yr = date.getFullYear(), month = +date.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? '0' + parseInt(date.getMonth() + 1) : date.getMonth() + 1,

    day = +date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' + date.getDate() : date.getDate(),
    newDate = yr + '-' + month + '-' + day + ' ' + date.getHours() + ':' + date.getMinutes() + ':' + date.getSeconds();
  $.ajax({
    url: '<?php echo base_url("comments/create");?>',
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      post_id: $("#postcommentid").val(),
      comment: $("textarea#comment").val(),
      created_on: newDate,
    },
    dataType: "text",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      if (data == 'Created') {

        alert("comment has been posted.");
        $('#postComments').modal('hide');
      }
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal inmodal" id="postComments" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content animated fadeIn">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Post a Comment</h4>
        <div class="row">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form" id="frmpostcomments" action="<?php echo base_url(" comments/create ");?>" method="post">

          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Comment</label>
            <input type="hidden" name="postcommentid" id="postcommentid" value="" />

            <textarea name="comment" required id="comment" cols="30" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Post Comment</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you edit in the relevant HTML to the code snippet? are you using a library for the modal? If so, which one?

Comment: Just posted the relevant HTML

Comment: who calls `postComment()` ? does showing the modal work?

Comment: The modal works perfectly, posting the comment to database  ...everything works just fine except 'hide' !

Comment: okay and just double checking you see the alert `alert("comment has been posted.");` too, right? and You exit the alert and the modal is still there?

Comment: No, the alert does not show... after posting nothing visually happens, only after manually closing the modal and checking the database, the comment is posted. but no alert nor hide is performed

Comment: since `$('#postComments').modal('hide');` seems correct you should check to see if `data == 'Created'` is actually true, if its false, then obviously your modal will not become hidden

Comment: Man oh man ! ... you were right !

Comment: no problem! when things don't make sense, always check your assumptions :)